# SQL Server Configuration Manager returns remote procedure call failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I open the SQL Server Configuration Manager and it returns remote procedure call failed.

[image]

This is Windows 7 Ultimate version, SQL Server 2008 R2 Express version with advanced services.

Previously I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express version and since I needed the full text search I uninstalled SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and then installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with advanced services.

P.s my RPC background service is running.

I executed the following command and it returned an error:

```
 C:\Users\venkat>mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL    Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

 Microsoft (R) MOF Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2006. All rights reserved.
 Parsing MOF file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
 MOF file has been successfully parsed
 Storing data in the repository...
```

Error:

> An error occurred while processing item 1 defined on lines 4 - 7 in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof:
>   Error Number: 0x80041003, Facility: WMI
>   Description: Access denied
>   Compiler returned error 0x80041003

Comment: Is your Remote Procedure Call service running ? check under services.msc

Answer (score 2):

In my case there were two instances of the "SQL server Configuration Manager" in SysWOW64. Only the latest version worked. The other version produced the RPC error message.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager10.msc FAILED
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc WORKED
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271), it worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by running the command prompt as administrator and typing the same commands for me. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to happen when .mof files (Managed Object Format (MOF)) don’t get installed and registered correctly during set-up. To resolve this issue, Execute the following mofcomp command in command prompt to re-register the *.mof files:

I am generally write down according to bit size. which OS you are using according to that you can execute the command

mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

Comment: I am using windows 7 ultimate version build 7610 sp1

Comment: updated after running your command. It returns an error.

Comment: after executing the command , what you are getting error. can you share that error.

Comment: Have you check out your OS, windows firewall and WMI privilege.

Comment: For 32-bit  mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
 
On a 64-bit operating system:
 
mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

Comment: @Venkat ..open the command prompt with elevated rights (run as administrator and accept the UAC prompt) and now run mofcomp again.

Comment: thanks. the command got executed succesfully with elevated rights but still I get the same error 'The remote procedure failed'